# Get LDAP username Invalid Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using code block below to get LDAP username (I am giving only first line)

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{

}
```

It gives me an error once I publish the asp.net MVC app to server.

> *ArgumentException: The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the domain parameter like this.

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain)) {
        // validate the credentials 
        result = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```